# How to put php inside JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

**I've tried (but its not working):**

```
<?php  
  $htmlString= 'testing';
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      var htmlString=<?php echo $htmlString; ?>;
      alert(htmlString);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the [tutorial](http://web-design.lovetoknow.com/Define_PHP_Variables_Inside_Javascript) that I've used for that purpose:

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php $htmlString= 'testing'; ?>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      // notice the quotes around the ?php tag         
      var htmlString="<?php echo $htmlString; ?>";
      alert(htmlString);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you run into problems like this one, a good idea is to check your browser for JavaScript errors. Different browsers have different ways of showing this, but look for a javascript console or something like that. Also, check the source of your page as viewed by the browser.

Sometimes beginners are confused about the quotes in the string: In the PHP part, you assigned `'testing'` to `$htmlString`. This puts a string value inside that variable, but the value does not have the quotes in it: They are just for the interpreter, so he knows: *oh, now comes a string literal*.

Comment: @inf3rno, if it's wrong, we should fix it! can't let a wrong answer here... what exactly is wrong? (I'm assuming you're objecting to the last paragraph... hm... kinda hard to explain this to a beginner - do you have a better take?)

Comment: @inf3rno, oh... I just saw your own answer. Hm... you have a point there... except, I think that for the level OP is ATM, it's a bit TMI. He seems to not have got his head wrapped around some basic stuff yet.

Comment: It's easy to explain, if you want to inject string to javascript code, you have to escape it for javascript... json_encode does that... It is very similar to sql injection prevention, by there you have to escape for sql...

Comment: it goes wrong when php variable contains ' mark. like "person's"

Comment: is this still valid AND **is this secure??**

Answer (score 32):

You're missing quotes around your string:

```
...
var htmlString="<?php echo $htmlString; ?>";
...
```

Comment: `$htmlString = "\""` huh, I wonder why that JavaScript suddenly stopped working...

Answer (score 13):

All the explanations above doesn't work if you work with .js files. If you want to parse PHP into .js files, you have to make changes on your server by modfiying the .htaccess in which the .js files reside using the following commands:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
</FilesMatch>
```

Then, a file test.js files containing the following code will execute .JS on client side with the parsed PHP on server-side:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction(){
   alert("Hello World!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()"><?php echo "My button";?></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

The only proper way to put server side data into generated javascript code:

```
<?php $jsString= 'testing'; ?>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">      
      var jsStringFromPhp=<?php echo json_encode($jsString); ?>;
      alert(jsStringFromPhp);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With simple quotes the content of your variable is not escaped against HTML and javascript, so it is vulnerable by XSS attacks...

For similar reasons I recommend to use `document.createTextNode()` instead of setting the `innerHTML`. Ofc. it is slower, but more secure...

Comment: Technically it's not the *only* way, but it's certainly a safe way. That said, one shouldn't be building JavaScript with PHP to begin with.

Comment: It depends on what kind of data would you like to send. The html unicode characters are not the same as the javascript unicode characters so you have to transform them... Another way to use REST services and a proper client side library to handle requests, for example extjs or backbone. Btw. you have to use json_encode in that case too...

Answer (score 7):

you need quotes around the string in javascript

```
var htmlString="<?php echo $htmlString; ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you need the quotes, but I just want to point out that there's a shorthand method of writing this same line of code

```
var htmlString="<?=$htmlString?>";
```

See you can leave out the "php echo" stuff and replace it with a simple "=".

Answer (score -1):

Let's see both the options:

1.) Use PHP inside Javascript

```
<script>
    <?php $temp = 'hello';?>
    console.log('<?php echo $temp; ?>');
</script>
```

Note: File name should be in .php only.

2.) Use Javascript variable inside PHP

```
<script>
  var res = "success";
</script>
<?php
   echo "<script>document.writeln(res);</script>";
?>
```