# How to access AJAX file from different folder in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have one form with Jquery validation which is working perfectly, Even AJAX is also working perfectly if I use my validation code with AJAX on the same page.

Now What I did, I create a file called as validation.js and I added my validation code with AJAX in it and I added a script like below in my view page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/validation.js"></script>
```

Then I clicked on submit button It's checked my validation even it also goes to AJAX URL which I entered but this time I haven't got output.

I am getting in Network tab in the browser my URL like this

`<?php echo base_url("index.php/user_control/admin_submit_from"); ?>`

I am using sublime text editor If I used above URL on the same page then the `base_url` color is showing in blue and If I used in validaion.js the color is showing in yellow.

Above URL Is not working from the validation.js file. Would you help me in this?

My Jquery validation with AJAX

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form[name='admin_form_submit']").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                 minlength:3,
                maxlength:50
            },

            lastname: {
                required: true,
                 minlength:3,
                maxlength:50
            },

    role:{
                required: true
            },

             inst_name:{
                required: true
            }
        },

         submitHandler: function(form) {
        //// form.submit();
         $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                  url: '<?php echo base_url("index.php/user_control/admin_submit_from"); ?>',
                 data: $('form[name="admin_form_submit"]').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
           });        
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345457/how-to-put-php-inside-javascript)

Comment: @SamuelAsor, But the same code is working If I enter on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the code worked in the first method was because it was included within a `PHP` file. Within a php file, you can embed `HTML`, `CSS`, `JS`, and that's why when you write something like this:

```
<script src='<?php echo $something; ?>'></script>
```

the value of that `$something` is echoed.

On the other hand, you cannot embed a php code inside a javascript file. The entire code will be treated as a `string`, and the reason why it is parsed that way.

So to solve you issue *(if you still want to put your js in a separate file)*, one of the ways to do that is to add a hidden `input` with your desired value, in your form, and use js to get it.

In your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_url" id="my_url" value="<?php echo base_url("index.php/user_control/admin_submit_from"); ?>">
```

Then you target it from your js file like so:

```
var myUrl = $('#my_url').val();
```

then update your `ajax` to:

```
$.ajax({
    // other objects and properties
    url: myUrl,
});
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can't execute php in a js file

create a global js variable in your php file with the url and reference that in your js file

index.php

```
<script>
var url = '<?php echo base_url("index.php/user_control/admin_submit_from"); ?>';
</script>
```

validation.js

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                  url: url,
                 data: $('form[name="admin_form_submit"]').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
           });        
        }
```

Comment: I tried your code but still getting <?php echo base_url("index.php/user_control/admin_submit_from"); ?>

Comment: I am getting PHP add also

Comment: I tried alert(url) and I got output like <?php echo base_url("index.php/user_control/admin_submit_from"); ?>. If I tried same code in same page then I got a output like http://localhost/drop/index.php/user_control/admin_submit_from

Comment: so if you do `<script>
var url = '<?php echo base_url("index.php/user_control/admin_submit_from"); ?>';console.log(url)
</script>` you still get the php not the url?

Comment: Console.log(url) is showing empty. I tried alert(URL) and I got PHP the code in it.

Comment: try `console.log(typeof(url))` and tell me the result

Comment: make sure you put the script tag before validation.js